# SailsJS - index.html is not working in SailsJS

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I added `index.html` to `assets` folder in `SailsJS`, but I can't visit it by `http://localhost`, but it did work visiting `http://localhost/index.html`.

What I tried:

1. As the comment suggested in the code as below:

   `/***************************************************************************
        *                                                                          *
        * Make the view located at`views/homepage.ejs`(or`views/homepage.jade`, *
        * etc. depending on your default view engine) your home page.              *
        *                                                                          *
        * (Alternatively, remove this and add an`index.html`file in your         *
        *`assets` directory)                                                      *
        *                                                                          *
        ***************************************************************************/

   ```
   /*'/': {
    view: 'homepage'
    },*/`
   ```
2. Add a new route in `routes.js` as below:

   `'GET /': {
       view: 'cn/homepage'
   }`

None is working and returned 404.

So what should be the possible cause of this? Seems the '/' is handled somewhere, but I didn't figure out where.

Appreciate the help provided, thanks.

Comment: What version of sails are you using ?

Comment: Version 0.12 is used.

Comment: Tested and working on V1.0, you should upgrade and test it !

Comment: Does your project require using version 0.12? If so, what is the incompatibility with newer versions of Sails? Sharing this on StackOverflow can help future development, so thanks in advance. If you are unfamiliar with the upgrade process or worried of breaking changes, here's the [upgrade doc](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/upgrading/to-v-1-0) for best practices with upgrading to Sails 1.x.

Comment: I don't think I can. Since we have a third party library which supports NodeJS less than version 7.0, and I can't even create Sails project with `sails new my-project` now. I'm thinking if it's the '/' been handled somewhere.